# Can I edit a binary (hex) file with PHP, replace a string and save without corrupting the binary?

Tags: php, binary

I have a little problem :)

1. I have a binary file -executable- which I want to edit and replace a
   string
2. I open the file with PHP, perform a replace and save it
3. Saved binary is corrupt.

If I do it using SED or any hexadecimal editor, it works fine.

Can I open, edit (replace a string) and save a binary file using PHP?

Thank you very much!

Comment: well, yes. What's your code look like?

Comment: And you don't think that showing the code you used to perform that in PHP would matter?

Comment: Yes, sorry. The code is this:

Comment: please edit your original question to put in your code. This is the normal way and it doesn't show in your comment.

Answer (score 2):

On systems which differentiate between binary and text files (i.e. Windows) the file must be opened with 'b' included in fopen() mode parameter. Then use fread and fwrite on the file.

```
<?php
$fp = fopen('binary_file.bin', 'w+b');
fwrite($fp, '1');
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: But this just completely overwrites the file without searching for a particular string, doesn't it?

Answer (score -1):

You could read the file byte by byte, doing a binary comparation, and a byte to byte replacement. Write PHP code that look like C code :D

Comment: What kind of answer is this? "Write PHP code that look like C code"?

Comment: What kind of comment is that? "What kind of answer is this?"

Comment: Peter comment is basically C with $ in the variables :D

What I am really suggesting, is doing byte operations, and avoid all the string parsing function of PHP. Using only the subset of file/byte array operations that PHP share with C.